# JsTree is not applied on a later built list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jstree

I have an Angular2 web application which loads a ul/li-list from a remote JSON object when a button is clicked.
The generated div and list looks like this:

```
<div class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default jstree-leaf" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="j1_loading" aria-busy="false" ng-reflect-inner-h-t-m-l="<ul class=&quot;.actual&quot;><li>Windows<ul><li>setupact.log</li><li>Tasks<ul><li>SCHEDLGU.TXT</li></ul></li><li>Logs<ul><li>CBS<ul><li>CBS.log</li></ul></li><li>DPX<ul><li>setupact.log</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>AppCompat<ul><li>Programs<ul><li>AEINV_PREVIOUS.xml</li><li>RecentFileCache.bcf</li><li>AEINV_WER_{91399519-4D7E-4F2D-8E40-5C55523C2307}_20160914_210543.xml</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>winsxs<ul><li>ManifestCache<ul><li>702349c5b78f9a04_blobs.bin</li></ul></li><li>poqexec.log</li></ul></li><li>rescache<ul><li>ResCache.mni</li></ul></li><li>System32<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Protect<ul><li>S-1-5-19<ul><li>Preferred</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>7B296FB0-376B-497e-B012-9C450E1B7327-5P-1.C7483456-A289-439d-8115-601632D005A0</li><li>winevt<ul><li>Logs<ul><li>Security.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Windows Firewall With Advanced Security%4Firewall.evtx</li><li>Windows PowerShell.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Dhcpv6-Client%4Admin.evtx</li><li>System.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience%4Program-Telemetry.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-WHEA%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Resource-Exhaustion-Detector%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-NetworkLocationWizard%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-LanguagePackSetup%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-OfflineFiles%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup%4ActionCenter.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-International%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-MUI%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Compat-Appraiser%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Diagnosis-DPS%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Application.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-BranchCacheSMB%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Bits-Client%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Known Folders API Service.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender%4WHC.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-HomeGroup Provider Service%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-ReliabilityAnalysisComponent%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-CodeIntegrity%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-WinRM%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience%4Program-Inventory.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Operational.evtx</li><li>Setup.evtx</li><li>Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2%4Operational.evtx</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>7B296FB0-376B-497e-B012-9C450E1B7327-5P-0.C7483456-A289-439d-8115-601632D005A0</li><li>wdi<ul><li>{86432a0b-3c7d-4ddf-a89c-172faa90485d}<ul><li>S-1-5-21-1426688081-248760799-3800414735-1001_UserData.bin</li></ul></li><li>ShutdownPerformanceDiagnostics_SystemData.bin</li><li>BootPerformanceDiagnostics_SystemData.bin</li><li>LogFiles<ul><li>WdiContextLog.etl.003</li><li>WdiContextLog.etl.002</li><li>WdiContextLog.etl.001</li><li>BootCKCL.etl</li><li>ShutdownCKCL.etl</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>LogFiles<ul><li>Scm<ul><li>a1cfa52f-06f2-418d-addb-cd6456d66f43</li><li>2c59ecaf-3a27-4640-9f4b-519b05bdd70f</li><li>5b184694-64c3-4633-94c5-945b3fa561d6</li><li>6b7ac694-8d6d-481b-9dd8-2a3a741ada6d</li><li>956981f2-9434-4ac7-92d1-255484e54e4d</li><li>bba67ad0-4ba0-4b44-827b-ff419b70c057</li><li>b9bee219-c29e-4310-819c-147a5a0e045e</li><li>731e9c62-95b5-4c8c-ab64-4cc591c9ff5b</li><li>9334c323-f100-4656-9ba0-e4aa69c0f9c2</li><li>d21f6024-191f-4454-bbbc-09a650da2549</li><li>a316e645-1c56-45a6-bd6a-7dca79778090</li><li>a6394592-54ce-4e93-8d64-1a068f462632</li><li>f1369a11-e983-4458-b390-712efa1cba44</li><li>38279e40-3dc1-4c28-a688-148aed61ff69</li><li>1ec9510d-a439-4950-9399-b6399edf9ea7</li><li>de8bae53-2809-4f75-85ef-427d364b9b2c</li><li>9b75c702-ea13-406a-badb-6c588ee4375b</li><li>de8699d2-8a05-42f7-8a85-5162af47d26a</li></ul></li><li>WMI<ul><li>RtBackup<ul><li>EtwRTDiagLog.etl</li><li>EtwRTEventLog-Application.etl</li><li>EtwRTEventLog-System.etl</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>spool<ul><li>drivers<ul><li>w32x86<ul><li>3<ul><li>mxdwdui.BUD</li></ul></li><li>PCC<ul><li>tsprint.inf_x86_neutral_c48d421ad2c1e3e3.cab</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Tasks<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Windows Defender<ul><li>MP Scheduled Scan</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>DriverStore<ul><li>INFCACHE.1</li><li>FileRepository<ul><li>prnep00l.inf_x86_neutral_3323920c1a72a42d<ul><li>prnep00l.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr009.inf_x86_neutral_3f6b69c8d1091fd8<ul><li>prnbr009.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnkm002.inf_x86_neutral_ded1a36701bddc86<ul><li>prnkm002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnca003.inf_x86_neutral_f0a023edfd5cd833<ul><li>prnca003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnca00d.inf_x86_neutral_8883e3ab4a33bfbb<ul><li>prnca00d.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr006.inf_x86_neutral_331a0c6df1c9d3e1<ul><li>prnbr006.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep004.inf_x86_neutral_25623e649d146f5d<ul><li>prnep004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnkm003.inf_x86_neutral_ea465b3729b37f54<ul><li>prnkm003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr005.inf_x86_neutral_407befecac90c7f1<ul><li>prnbr005.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc003.inf_x86_neutral_e9198ff5f961d947<ul><li>prnrc003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>bth.inf_x86_neutral_a6bf6d613b46f6a5<ul><li>bth.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnin004.inf_x86_neutral_2aba7beb4ab9a9e8<ul><li>prnin004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnnr004.inf_x86_neutral_15e7dc89d102e928<ul><li>prnnr004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnin002.inf_x86_neutral_b9fa18a8d63d5294<ul><li>prnin002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnca00g.inf_x86_neutral_b19defbd7969a7c7<ul><li>prnca00g.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnhp005.inf_x86_neutral_9307c57b91a7985e<ul><li>prnhp005.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc006.inf_x86_neutral_404ca57b9d9c1e47<ul><li>prnrc006.PNF</li></ul></li><li>amdsata.inf_x86_neutral_5c3d0d1e97e99e10<ul><li>amdsata.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc005.inf_x86_neutral_73b01a2655fdb5c5<ul><li>prnrc005.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnca00f.inf_x86_neutral_b94365c0e502f290<ul><li>prnca00f.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep00a.inf_x86_neutral_d4494950448771ed<ul><li>prnep00a.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnge001.inf_x86_neutral_51cbe14e4cdde8c2<ul><li>prnge001.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnkm004.inf_x86_neutral_b456c14d5367f83c<ul><li>prnkm004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr008.inf_x86_neutral_87aae9d395393afd<ul><li>prnbr008.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnok002.inf_x86_neutral_436ff5d24333cca0<ul><li>prnok002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnin003.inf_x86_neutral_dca922447801904c<ul><li>prnin003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnsa002.inf_x86_neutral_db272f9cd17a383f<ul><li>prnsa002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr007.inf_x86_neutral_af94d26aafd1ca3a<ul><li>prnbr007.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep003.inf_x86_neutral_342be98eb74e1449<ul><li>prnep003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep005.inf_x86_neutral_f4a4a2a89cb57323<ul><li>prnep005.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc004.inf_x86_neutral_7d5665e9e43f678d<ul><li>prnrc004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnhp003.inf_x86_neutral_8685826a5ca37e6b<ul><li>prnhp003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>iastorv.inf_x86_neutral_0bcee2057afcc090<ul><li>iastorv.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnca00b.inf_x86_neutral_c675b60dd45218c1<ul><li>prnca00b.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc007.inf_x86_neutral_cfebba21b1c02dd7<ul><li>prnrc007.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnle003.inf_x86_neutral_a8106f7f3af21d88<ul><li>prnle003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr002.inf_x86_neutral_1d14699bf2d4d936<ul><li>prnbr002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnnr003.inf_x86_neutral_02802729a95f0eed<ul><li>prnnr003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep00c.inf_x86_neutral_92ff44dcbf1c760c<ul><li>prnep00c.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnsv003.inf_x86_neutral_2011fa0a7f786266<ul><li>prnsv003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnnr002.inf_x86_neutral_b9a1c43c0cb6c940<ul><li>prnnr002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>faxcn002.inf_x86_neutral_29a66691dd7a46a5<ul><li>faxcn002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnod002.inf_x86_neutral_c36a5fe1ac15a734<ul><li>prnod002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc00b.inf_x86_neutral_354df7938905aa3b<ul><li>prnrc00b.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep00b.inf_x86_neutral_d0e9433101a2df79<ul><li>prnep00b.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnsv004.inf_x86_neutral_3ee5a15023f3b3ed<ul><li>prnsv004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prngt002.inf_x86_neutral_a10ecaa46786286d<ul><li>prngt002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>nvraid.inf_x86_neutral_0276fc3b3ea60d41<ul><li>nvraid.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr004.inf_x86_neutral_a976dec554a0be13<ul><li>prnbr004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnep002.inf_x86_neutral_9111d9b86cbd3f64<ul><li>prnep002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnrc002.inf_x86_neutral_3fb2e6c401a9c7d8<ul><li>prnrc002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnbr003.inf_x86_neutral_21c4516754f2bda5<ul><li>prnbr003.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnle004.inf_x86_neutral_60637fb8287b0bdb<ul><li>prnle004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnkm005.inf_x86_neutral_a2013031e279b6f6<ul><li>prnkm005.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prngt004.inf_x86_neutral_f7b569fe96e4f7ae<ul><li>prngt004.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnhp002.inf_x86_neutral_e6daa9c39ac001a3<ul><li>prnhp002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnfx002.inf_x86_neutral_f83f67e1c22e557b<ul><li>prnfx002.PNF</li></ul></li><li>prnhp004.inf_x86_neutral_95288ae6f32f1fe7<ul><li>prnhp004.PNF</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>SMI<ul><li>Store<ul><li>Machine<ul><li>SCHEMA.DAT{f74722ed-7b07-11e6-b6ad-0800273c6b02}.TM.blf</li><li>SCHEMA.DAT.LOG1</li><li>SCHEMA.DAT{f74722ed-7b07-11e6-b6ad-0800273c6b02}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms</li><li>SCHEMA.DAT</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>CodeIntegrity<ul><li>bootcat.cache</li></ul></li><li>wbem<ul><li>Repository<ul><li>MAPPING1.MAP</li><li>MAPPING2.MAP</li><li>MAPPING3.MAP</li><li>OBJECTS.DATA</li><li>INDEX.BTR</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>wfp<ul><li>wfpdiag.etl</li></ul></li><li>config<ul><li>SOFTWARE.LOG1</li><li>SECURITY.LOG1</li><li>SAM</li><li>DEFAULT.LOG1</li><li>COMPONENTS.LOG1</li><li>systemprofile<ul><li>AppData<ul><li>LocalLow<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>CryptnetUrlCache<ul><li>MetaData<ul><li>7396C420A8E1BC1DA97F1AF0D10BAD21</li><li>57C8EDB95DF3F0AD4EE2DC2B8CFD4157</li><li>37C951188967C8EB88D99893D9D191FE</li><li>21253908F3CB05D51B1C2DA8B681A785</li><li>A1377F7115F1F126A15360369B165211</li><li>F90F18257CBB4D84216AC1E1F3BB2C76</li><li>A583E2A51BFBDC1E492A57B7C8325850</li><li>3130B1871A126520A8C47861EFE3ED4D</li><li>696F3DE637E6DE85B458996D49D759AD</li><li>4C7F163ED126D5C3CB9457F68EC64E9E</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>SYSTEM</li><li>DEFAULT</li><li>COMPONENTS{6cced2ed-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TM.blf</li><li>SAM.LOG1</li><li>SYSTEM.LOG1</li><li>COMPONENTS</li><li>SECURITY</li><li>COMPONENTS{6cced2ed-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms</li><li>COMPONENTS{6cced2ed-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms</li><li>TxR<ul><li>{6cced300-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms</li><li>{6cced300-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms</li><li>{6cced300-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TxR.blf</li><li>{6cced301-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TM.blf</li><li>{6cced301-6e01-11de-8bed-001e0bcd1824}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms</li></ul></li><li>SOFTWARE</li></ul></li><li>NetworkList<ul><li>Icons<ul><li>{1ED31542-AA58-4CD5-A56A-B9007AB965C3}_16.bin</li><li>{1ED31542-AA58-4CD5-A56A-B9007AB965C3}_24.bin</li><li>{1ED31542-AA58-4CD5-A56A-B9007AB965C3}_48.bin</li><li>{1ED31542-AA58-4CD5-A56A-B9007AB965C3}_32.bin</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>catroot2<ul><li>{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}<ul><li>catdb</li></ul></li><li>{127D0A1D-4EF2-11D1-8608-00C04FC295EE}<ul><li>catdb</li></ul></li><li>edb.log</li><li>edb004E5.log</li><li>edb.chk</li><li>edb004E4.log</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>SoftwareDistribution<ul><li>DataStore<ul><li>DataStore.edb</li><li>Logs<ul><li>edb.chk</li><li>edb.log</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>ReportingEvents.log</li></ul></li><li>ServiceProfiles<ul><li>NetworkService<ul><li>NTUSER.DAT.LOG1</li><li>NTUSER.DAT</li><li>AppData<ul><li>Roaming<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>SoftwareProtectionPlatform<ul><li>Cache<ul><li>cache.dat</li></ul></li><li>tokens.dat</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Local<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Media Player<ul><li>CurrentDatabase_372.wmdb</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Temp<ul><li>MpCmdRun.log</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>LocalService<ul><li>NTUSER.DAT.LOG1</li><li>NTUSER.DAT</li><li>AppData<ul><li>Roaming<ul><li>PeerNetworking<ul><li>idstore.sst</li><li>idstore.sst.new</li></ul></li><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Crypto<ul><li>RSA<ul><li>S-1-5-19<ul><li>7e22207fe9846926e18c29d3e675240e_f98e9ddc-0e1b-4293-b1aa-bc41c96b9f31</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Local<ul><li>FontCache-S-1-5-21-1426688081-248760799-3800414735-1001.dat</li><li>FontCache-System.dat</li><li>FontCache-FontFace.dat</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>bootstat.dat</li><li>servicing<ul><li>Sessions<ul><li>Sessions.xml</li><li>Sessions.back.xml</li><li>30543655_539879863.xml</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Temp<ul><li>MpCmdRun.log</li><li>MpSigStub.log</li></ul></li><li>inf<ul><li>setupapi.ev1</li><li>setupapi.dev.log</li><li>setupapi.app.log</li></ul></li><li>Microsoft.NET<ul><li>Framework<ul><li>v4.0.30319<ul><li>ngen.log</li><li>ngen_service.log</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>WindowsUpdate.log</li></ul></li><li>System Volume Information<ul><li>Syscache.hve</li><li>Syscache.hve.LOG1</li><li>{ebac27bb-7b10-11e6-a5bc-0800273c6b02}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}</li></ul></li><li>pagefile.sys</li><li>Users<ul><li>vagrant<ul><li>ntuser.dat.LOG1</li><li>NTUSER.DAT</li><li>AppData<ul><li>LocalLow<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>CryptnetUrlCache<ul><li>Content<ul><li>B912B2C6928A18B8CD7D50CF08BEA95B_87708DAABE1AF38B603CEFBE5F2B3276</li></ul></li><li>MetaData<ul><li>EDC238BFF48A31D55A97E1E93892934B_C20E0DA2D0F89FE526E1490F4A2EE5AB</li><li>B912B2C6928A18B8CD7D50CF08BEA95B_87708DAABE1AF38B603CEFBE5F2B3276</li><li>40E450F7CE13419A2CCC2A5445035A0A_97482851B9CF8FBB790FA8AEAB0C772D</li><li>C0018BB1B5834735BFA60CD063B31956</li><li>7396C420A8E1BC1DA97F1AF0D10BAD21</li><li>57C8EDB95DF3F0AD4EE2DC2B8CFD4157</li><li>DCE3BDBF5BDD86E2AB5B471CB90709B4_A7704BF276C97AA4D70879F611AA7DB9</li><li>37C951188967C8EB88D99893D9D191FE</li><li>C46E7B0F942663A1EDC8D9D6D7869173_42820CDFEA41DC84AAB89A6B63561873</li><li>21253908F3CB05D51B1C2DA8B681A785</li><li>FB788E090BC1F3AA2FBC9E8FB2859601</li><li>F90F18257CBB4D84216AC1E1F3BB2C76</li><li>696F3DE637E6DE85B458996D49D759AD</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Roaming<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Windows<ul><li>Recent<ul><li>CustomDestinations<ul><li>d93f411851d7c929.customDestinations-ms</li></ul></li><li>AutomaticDestinations<ul><li>7e4dca80246863e3.automaticDestinations-ms</li><li>1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Local<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Windows<ul><li>Explorer<ul><li>thumbcache_256.db</li><li>thumbcache_32.db</li><li>thumbcache_idx.db</li></ul></li><li>Temporary Internet Files<ul><li>counters.dat</li></ul></li><li>WebCache<ul><li>V01.log</li><li>WebCacheV01.dat</li><li>V01.chk</li></ul></li><li>UsrClass.dat</li><li>UsrClass.dat.LOG1</li><li>Caches<ul><li>cversions.1.db</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Internet Explorer<ul><li>MSIMGSIZ.DAT</li><li>Tiles<ul><li>pin-2845162440<ul><li>msapplication.xml</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Recovery<ul><li>High<ul><li>Last Active<ul><li>RecoveryStore.{AC08E291-7B19-11E6-917C-0800273C6B02}.dat</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Feeds<ul><li>FeedsStore.feedsdb-ms</li><li>{5588ACFD-6436-411B-A5CE-666AE6A92D3D}~<ul><li>WebSlices~<ul><li>Suggested Sites~.feed-ms</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Media Player<ul><li>CurrentDatabase_372.wmdb</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>IconCache.db</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Public<ul><li>Libraries<ul><li>RecordedTV.library-ms</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>ProgramData<ul><li>Microsoft<ul><li>Windows Defender<ul><li>Support<ul><li>MPLog-07132009-215552.log</li></ul></li><li>Scans<ul><li>History<ul><li>Service<ul><li>Unknown.Log</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Search<ul><li>Data<ul><li>Applications<ul><li>Windows<ul><li>MSS.log</li><li>Windows.edb</li><li>GatherLogs<ul><li>SystemIndex<ul><li>SystemIndex.2.gthr</li><li>SystemIndex.2.Crwl</li><li>SystemIndex.1.Crwl</li><li>SystemIndex.1.gthr</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>MSS.chk</li><li>Projects<ul><li>SystemIndex<ul><li>PropMap<ul><li>CiPT0000.000</li></ul></li><li>SecStore<ul><li>CiST0000.002</li><li>CiST0000.001</li><li>CiST0000.000</li></ul></li><li>Indexer<ul><li>CiFiles<ul><li>CiAD0002.000</li><li>CiAD0002.001</li><li>00010001.ci</li><li>00010008.wid</li><li>00010004.wid</li><li>INDEX.002</li><li>INDEX.001</li><li>INDEX.000</li><li>00010001.dir</li><li>00010006.wid</li><li>CiAB0002.001</li><li>CiAB0002.000</li><li>CiAB0002.002</li><li>00010003.wid</li><li>CiAD0002.002</li><li>00010005.wid</li><li>00010007.ci</li><li>00010009.wid</li><li>00010005.ci</li><li>00010001.wid</li><li>00010005.dir</li><li>00010009.ci</li><li>00010007.wid</li><li>00010009.dir</li><li>00010002.wid</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li>RAC<ul><li>PublishedData<ul><li>RacWmiDatabase.sdf</li></ul></li><li>StateData<ul><li>RacWmiEventData.dat</li><li>RacWmiDataBookmarks.dat</li><li>RacDatabase.sdf</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Windows<ul><li>DRM<ul><li>drmstore.hds</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>Diagnosis<ul><li>ETLLogs<ul><li>ShutdownLogger<ul><li>AutoLogger-Diagtrack-Listener.etl</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>events01.rbs</li></ul></li><li>IlsCache<ul><li>ilrcache.xml</li><li>imcrcache.xml</li></ul></li><li>Network<ul><li>Downloader<ul><li>qmgr1.dat</li><li>qmgr0.dat</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>"><ul class=".actual"><li>Windows<ul><li>setupact.log</li><li>Tasks<ul><li>SCHEDLGU.TXT</li></ul> .... etc.
```

My Javascript code:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('button').on('click', function() {
                $('.jstree').jstree();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My **problem**: When the dom of this UL/LI-list is being built and generated by Angular2, the jstree is not getting applied. Instead I receive a normal list.

I tried several ways, having the jstree also loaded on the document ready function, without success:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
             $(".jstree").jstree();
        }
</script>
```

Appreciate any help or hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really invoke the code like you shown, Angular app is not in the DOM yet when document ready is called. If you need to use a jQuery plugin inside Angular 2, you should invoke it in a component's `ngOnInit`. [Refer here for sample angular2 component](http://learnangular2.com/components/).

Comment: Thanks @Capaj. The angular app is loaded already. The content of the JSON request is not loaded yet. So my problem is not with a component, but the reflected content which you correctly said is not yet in the DOM.